# filter in groupby for only like columns python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am looking to filter a dataframe by reducing the columns to be only ones that have 1 unique value.

take the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[4, 5],
                     'id2':[4, 4],
                      'prod':['prod1', 'prod1'],
                      'amount':[45.0, 45.0],
                      'date':['2018-06-06', '2018-05-06'],
                      'region':['east', 'east']})
```

I would like to group by id2, and then remove any columns where there are more that 1 unique value.

```
df
   amount        date  id  id2   prod region
0    45.0  2018-06-06   4    4  prod1   east
1    45.0  2018-05-06   5    4  prod1   east
```

output should look like:

```
   amount  id2   prod region
0    45.0    4  prod1   east
1    45.0    4  prod1   east
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `groupby` and then look for columns where unique values are equal to 1.

```
col = (df.groupby(['id2']).nunique() == 1).any()
df[col.index[col]]
```

Output:

```
  id2   prod    amount  region
0   4   prod1   45.0    east
1   4   prod1   45.0    east
```

Comment: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique'

Comment: @MattW. which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: '0.19.2' - I'm trying to update pandas in my conda environment and its saying 

Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem with the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do without using groupby since id2 has one unique value.

```
# count unique values per column
d = df.nunique(axis=0)

# select columns with 1 unique value
names = d[d == 1].index.tolist()

# get outpput
print(df[names])

   amount  id2   prod region
0    45.0    4  prod1   east
1    45.0    4  prod1   east
```

Comment: Shorter version:  `df[df.columns[df.nunique() == 1]]`

Comment: got the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique', also I have ~100k rows so I will need the groupby because I want to do this by each group. Just didn't add that in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Within a `loc` in order to take advantage of boolean indexing

```
df.loc[:, df.nunique().eq(1)]

   id2   prod  amount region
0    4  prod1    45.0   east
1    4  prod1    45.0   east
```

---

Similar answer but using a `lambda` instead.  This avoids dependence on referring to `df` twice and is completely inline.

```
df.loc[:, lambda d: d.nunique().eq(1)]
```